# How to delete a record from Hadoop AvroContainer in Azure blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, avro

I have been storing messages from different devices in `Azure Blob Storage` in AVRO format.

One of the devices got malfunctioned, and it ended up dumping "junk" messages. Now there is a task to search and delete messages from a particular device. Hence I wrote below code.

Loop through each `Blob` in a  `containers` and find the message

```
  foreach (var container in client.ListContainers(null, ContainerListingDetails.All))
  {
         if (permissions.PublicAccess == BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob || permissions.PublicAccess == BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container)
         {
              //for each blob
              foreach (var blobItem in container.ListBlobs(null, true))
              {
                     if (blobItem is CloudBlockBlob)
                     {
                         string blobname = ((CloudBlockBlob)blobItem).Name;
                         var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobname);

                          using (var myBlob = blob.OpenRead())
                          {
                             using (var reader = AvroContainer.CreateGenericReader(myBlob))
                             {
                                 while (reader.MoveNext())
                                 {
                                    foreach (dynamic avroRecord in reader.Current.Objects)
                                    {
                                          var eventData = new AvroEventData(avroRecord);
                                          var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body);

                                           JObject _json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

                                           //DeserializeObject and check the device ID
                                           // if found, then delete
                                           // but how do I delete? do I get reference here?
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                        }
                    }
              }
         }
  }
```

Above code, able to find the message based on message ID, but how do I delete it now?  `reader` may not help in deleting!

**Note: I do not want to delete entire `blob` because it might contain messages from other working devices.**

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue before(but it's not avro format), after some research and searching by google, I found it's hard to modify a blob when it's hosted in azure.

My solution is that download the file to local, then modify it as per your code, at last you can upload the modified file into azure blob storage. All the steps can be done via code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it will solve the issue, but very time consuming and expensive operation.

Comment: @kudlatiger, yes it's time consuming, but for operation fee, both of them should be equal unless the values need to be deleted are in the front of the file.

Comment: Okay, I think many might have faced this issue and Microsoft could help us here if I get more upvotes

Comment: @kudlatiger, I don't think so even you get more upvotes here. The best way is that submit a support request to MS support.